# How to show the download link in grid in backend (without ui component ) in magento 2

Tags: grid, backend, magento-2.2.5

I have custom grid and front end form in my module.

The form is submitted via frontend and saved in DB.

I am showing all the records in backend grid.

One of its field is file uploder field.

While submitting the form , I have save the uploded files in below folder path

```
**pub/media/myfolder/example.pdf**
```

And i also saved the path of the file in DB.

Now i wish to show the download link of the pdf file in admin grid.

Please provide me a solution how to add download link in admin grid

The below one is a resume uploder field

```
$this->addColumn(
            'resume', [
                'header' => __('Resume'),
                'index' => 'resume'
            ]
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this using render.

```
$this->addColumn(
            'resume', [
                'header' => __('Resume'),
                'index' => 'resume',
                'renderer'  => '<Vendor>\<Module>\Block\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Edit\Tab\Renderer\RenderName'
            ]
        );
```

After that Make renderer file RenderName.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
namespace <vendor>\<ModuleName>\Block\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Edit\Tab\Renderer;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
/**
 * Description of TestId
 *
 * @author dharmendra
 */
class RenderName extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{
    /** Url Path */
    const URL_PATH = 'test/test/test';

    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    private $urlBuilder;
    public function __construct(
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * get category name
     * @param  DataObject $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(DataObject $row)
    {
        return '<a href="' . $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(self::URL_PATH, ['id' => $row->getIdentifier()]) . '" target="_blank">' . __('Preview') . '</a>';
    }
}
```

After that check. You have to get link in your grid.
Still you have getting any issue let me know.

Make Url as per your need.

Comment: But tyou have mentioned url path as static, each resuem field have different pdf files

Comment: You have print $row->getData() and you will get which you have need.

Comment: I have just add example of url.

Comment: Hi it works and shows the file preview, thank you, but i need to download the file

Comment: If you download the file you can have to add controller for that.